# How to pass marginBottom to a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the following ui-component:

```
const StyledLabel = styled.div`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};
`;

const Label = ({
  text,
  marginBottom,
}) => (
  <StyledLabel
    style={{ marginBottom }}
  >
    {text}
  </StyledLabel>
);
```

What I want to do is remove the style attribute and have styled-components handle margin-bottom... So I now have:

```
const StyledLabel = styled.div`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};
  margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.marginBottom};
`;

const Label = ({
  text,
  marginBottom,
}) => (
  <StyledLabel
    marginBottom={marginBottom}
  >
    {text}
  </StyledLabel>
);
```

The problem with the above is the CSS being applied to the element is:

```
margin-bottom: 8;
```

Not the desired `8px` -- Can I get styled-components to magically add the `px` the way `style` does? Or do I need to update my app from passing marginBottom `8` to `8px` ?

Comment: Can you just change `StyledLabel` to append the `px`, like


```const StyledLabel = styled.div`
color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.marginBottom + 'px'};
`;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey mate why you want to mix `css` rules with your components, I think that you can send different `className` and create your `css` rules in a `file.css` and it would be easier to manage. However if you want to continue with your code you need just to add the `px`

```
margin-bottom: {${props.marginBottom}px`};
```

Or you can create a `const` and add it after.